# center of the universe

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is meant by the center of the universe?

I read this sentence:

> She thinks she is the center of the universe.

But I couldn't figure out the meaning.

Comment: I suggest you make use of any bilingual dictionary your language may have.

Comment: A bilingual dictionary from what language to what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that she thinks she is so **important** to everyone, and everything that happens has something to do with her.
This sentence suggests that she thinks she is **the most important person** in the world. In other words, it might be true to say that the speaker sees her as a **narcissistic** human being.